# Downloadable Fonts not caching correctly

Tags: android, android-support-library

My application uses Android Downloadable Fonts via `Support Library 27.0.2` to set custom fonts on XML, as per the [API Guide on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html). The fonts are applied normally except the first time each font family is drawn on the screen.

For example: if I open `ActivityA`, its `Toolbar` will show `Tab1` title with default Roboto, but `Tab2` and `Tab3` will use my custom font. The second time `ActivityA` is opened (without closing the application), the issue doesn't happen and all Tabs will use the custom font. Besides the Tab titles, I also noticed the issue on Toolbar. It's the same case: after first opening, the font is applied correctly.

`res/values/font_certs.xml` and `res/font/font.xml` files were generated by Android Studio and are just like the ones provided in documentation:

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs"
    app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
    app:fontProviderQuery="Lato" />
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<application ...>
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

And `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <array name="preloaded_fonts">
        <item>@font/lato</item>
        <item>@font/lato_bold</item>
        <item>@font/lato_light</item>
        <item>@font/raleway</item>
        <item>@font/raleway_semibold</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

The fonts are applied using the following theme on `AppBarLayout`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/raleway</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

The project uses the following versions:

```
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.0'
playServicesVersion = '11.6.0'
```

The problem was reproduced using an AVD with API 21 and on a real Nexus 6P running API 27. Seems like there is a problem with Font Cache. How can I fix it or better investigate this issue?

Comment: Maybe this will help you a bit: https://medium.com/@romainguy/androids-font-renderer-c368bbde87d9

Comment: I sometimes get a movement for textview's text, may be it takes a second to fetch the said font from provider's cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I have not found a way to fix the issue besides using offline fonts. In this case I replaced the `font.xml` files by the `font.ttf` ones downloaded from Google Fonts and removed the `preloaded_fonts` meta tag in the manifest. This caused an increase of about 200KB in the APK size (for 5 fonts).